# Editable units in HTML <input type=“number”>

Tags: jquery, html, forms, html-input

I want the user to enter numbers with units like "px", "em" or "%" and then increase/decrease value using arrows.

Similar to this [jQuery UI Spinner demo](http://jqueryui.com/spinner/#currency), but with option to type any unit right inside input field.

**UPD:**
I came up with this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29368532/editable-units-in-html-input-type-number#answer-29370025) that works for me.

Comment: have you tried anything from your side?

Comment: I have tried to modify jQuery UI example with no luck. Searching for similar plugins didn't help either. Answer from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28605416/display-of-units-in-html-stepper-input-type-number#answer-29271539) is close to what I am looking for. I am trying to modify it to fit my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [N K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2264512/n-k) for his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28605416/display-of-units-in-html-stepper-input-type-number#answer-29271539). Here is modified snippet that support units edit.

```js
$("#value").on("change", function(){
    var units = $("#units").val();
    console.log(units);
    $(".fake input").val(this.value + units);
});
$(".fake input").on("change", function(){
    var value = this.value.match(/(\d*\.?\d*)(.*)/);
    $("#value").val(value[1]);
    $("#units").val(value[2]);
});
```

```css
.fake {
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
    left: 2px;
    float: left;
}
.fake input {
    width: 145px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="original">
    <input id="value" type="number" step="1"/>
    <input id="units" type="hidden" name="units" value="px"/>
</div>
<div class="fake">
    <input type="text" value="0px"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[Fiddle][solution]    
[solution]: http://jsfiddle.net/apurvaojas/yvLj1400/1/
```

```js
$("input[type='number']").change(function(){
    var ip = $(this);
    switch($('select').val())
    {
   case 'per': $('div.block').width(ip.val()+"%"); 
   break;

   case 'em': $('div.block').width(ip.val()+"em");
   break;
            
            case 'px': $('div.block').width(ip.val()+"px");
   break;
   
   default: return; 
  }

});
```

```css
div.block{
    background: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top:10px;
}
.container{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" name="val">
    <select>
  <option value="per">%</option>
  <option value="em">em</option>
  <option value="px">px</option>
  
</select>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="block"></div>    
    </div>
```

I think this may solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not what I was looking for. It should support any units, not only from the list, so user can edit it right inside the input field.